# Angular interceptor reload the view after get refresh token

Tags: angularjs, authentication, jwt

I have an implementation of JWT and when the token expires im get 401 and then i do this:

1. send request to get new token.
   2.resend what the user request before.

Now before this the data isnt display in the page because the token is invalid, but now after the token is valid and i resend the request the user made, how i can refresh the state or the controller to auto show the data that the user ask before?

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                var $http = $injector.get('$http');
                AuthService.getRefreshToken().then(function(res) {

               //here im sending back the original user request again
//and now when the data is coming back because the token is valid now i want display that to the user
                    return $http(rejection.config);
                });

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and i use this module:

[angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth)

After you add this to your app, just add this code:

```
'responseError': function(rejection) {
            if (rejection.status === 401) {
                AuthService.getRefreshToken().then(function(res) {
                     // make sure you are inject the authService
                     authService.loginConfirmed();                 
                });
            }
        }
```

And thats all, your code will continue to work.

Comment: Looks like the interceptor just hangs in Angular 1.6 and doesn't rethrow anything.